# Efficient writing to a Compact Flash in python

Tags: python, python-2.4

I'm writing a gui to do perform a glorified 'dd'.

I could just subprocess to 'dd' but I thought I might as well use python's `open()`/`read()`/`write()` if I can as it'll let me display progress much more easily.

Prompted by [this link](http://blog.johnford.info/reimplementing-a-subset-of-dd-in-python/) here I have:

```
input = open('filename.img', 'rb')
output = open("/dev/sdc", 'wb')
while True:
    buffer = input.read(1024)
    if buffer:
        output.write(buffer)
    else:
        break
input.close()
output.close()
```

...however it is horribly slow. Or at least far slower than `dd`. (around 4-5x slower)

I had a play and noticed altering the number of bytes 'buffered' had a huge affect on the speed of completion. Raising it to 2048 for example seems to half the time taken. Perhaps going OT for SO here but I guess the flash has an optimum number of bytes to be written at once? Could anyone suggest how I discover this?

The image & card are 1Gb so I would very much like to return to the ~5 minutes dd took if possible. I appreciate that in all likelihood I won't match it.

Rather than trial and error, would anyone be able to suggest a way to optimise the above code and reasoning as to why it works? Especially what value for input.read() for example?

One restriction: python 2.4.3 on linux (centos5) (please don't hurt me)

Answer (score 1):

Speed depending on buffer size is unrelated to the specific characteristics of compact flash, but inherent to all I/O with (relatively) slow devices, even to all kinds of system calls. You should make the buffer size as large as possible without exhausting memory - 2MiB should be enough for a Flash drive.

You should use the `time` and `strace` utilities to determine why your program is slower. If `time` shows a large `user/real` (large meaning greater than `0.1`), you can optimize your Python interpreter - cpython 2.4 is pretty slow, and you're creating new objects all the time instead of writing into a preallocated buffer. If there is a significant difference in `sys` timings, analyze the syscalls made by both programs (with `strace`) and try to emit the ones `dd` does.

Also note that you **must** call `fsync` (or execute the `sync` program) afterwards to measure the real time it took writing the file to disk (or open the output file with `O_DIRECT`). Otherwise, the operating system will let your program exit and just keep all the written data in buffers that are then continually written out to the actual disk. To test that you're doing it right, remove the disk immediately after your program is finished. Note that the speed difference can be staggering. This effect is less noticeable if your disk(CF card) is way larger than the available physical memory.

Comment: Thanks for this, it makes perfect sense. Yep I found out rather quickly I was being silly limiting myself to K's (suggested by [the link](http://blog.johnford.info/reimplementing-a-subset-of-dd-in-python/)) rather than M's. Hoping you can re-read my own edited answer.

Comment: Yep as said in comments to my answer I'll try a sync. I have previously been pulling the card out as soon as I've seen it finish, wondering if this was the cause but had it verify as ok. Might need to double check the verification!

Answer (score 0):

So with a little help, I've removed the 'buffer' bit completely and added an `os.fsync()`.

```
import os

input = open('filename.img', 'rb')
output = open("/dev/sdc", 'wb')
output.write(input.read())
input.close()
output.close()
outputfile.flush()
os.fsync(outputfile.fileno())
```

Comment: This program just copies the first 1024 bytes. If you match it against `dd bs=1024 count=1`, you'll see that dd will probably not take 5 minutes for the same task.

Comment: Whoops yes!! My paste here was actually a typo. My actual code does what is now reflected in the edit. Again, md5sums are ok, the flash card performs its purpose perfectly (/ of an embedded system) I just can't believe it takes 5 seconds to burn it...

Comment: Using `read` without an argument reads the entire file into memory. This prevents the program for working with Larger-than-4GiB files on 32bit architectures and make it extremely slow for large disk images otherwise, so it's not a good idea. I think we've both overlooked one critical aspect: When `close` returns, the data may **not** be on the physical disk due to OS buffering. The speedups gained by this can be huge (100x is not unheard of; you seem to be experiencing a speedup in that vicinity). I updated my answer to add a paragraph explaining how to avoid this miscalculation.

Comment: Good point, I'll pop a sync in tomorrow and see how it goes. I had noticed python not writing everything to a file until I called `file.close()` but had assumed that sync'd it until now. The images are 1Gb.

Comment: 1GB is really small, especially if your free memory is larger than that (and that will usually be the case on a modern system). I hope for detailled results tomorrow ;)

Comment: As expected, `sync` takes a short while.

Comment: You still have the Python buffer, only implicitely (it's not a named variable anymore, but you still need to allocate the memory). Also, note that you can simply use the `sync` function from `<unistd.h>`. However, note that `sync` waits for **all** filesystem operations. You probably want to use `fsync`(only wait for operations on *your* file) instead.

Comment: Yep. I've just checked the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) and will go with `outputfile.flush()` then `os.fsync(outputfile.fileno())` Who would've thought it.. someone else already had this problem and wrote a handy function ;-)